# JS vs Media Queries for website design

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

I'm beginning to design a website for multiple devices: desktops/laptops, tablets (e.g. iPad, Galaxy Tab, and mobile devices (e.g. iPhones).

I currently have a few pages that have some javascript to redirect to completely different subdomains. For example, if a user visits `www.example.com` on an iPhone, they are redirected to `m.example.com` or `t.example.com` if they are on a tablet. Obviously this requires you to create different pages that are likely to have similar content whereas a media query would allow you just to lay things out slightly differently depending on screen size.

So it seems to me that media queries would be the preferred choice for handling different screen resolutions. This leaves me with some questions though. Say for example you have a navigation bar on the desktop site that would be better served with something like a `select` on the mobile sites. What would be the best way to implement this?

Apologies for my perhaps incoherent rambling but I guess my question is what is the best way to implement a mobile version of a site where the differences may not just be limited to layout (e.g. with simple media queries) but may require different elements on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are usually the best solution for what you're trying to achieve. If you start creating separate versions for separate devices you're going to give yourself a real headache trying to keep everything up to date. It's much better to have one set of code that will adapt itself to the device the user is using.

Have a look at the Twitter Bootstrap project. It's a ready-made framework that can help you put together your responsive design.

Comment: Thank you for a clear and concise answer and +1 for the excellent link!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create one view , one js and one css and handle all things in single file or for better performance I would suggest using MVC pattern,
You will need to detect user agent then on the basis load respective view + css + js. 
Load things like this page+agent+extention

For Instance:

home.web.html, home.tablet.html, home.mobile.html

home.web.js, home.tablet.js, home.mobile.js (you can also make single js file)

You can place one css that handle layout through media queries

**Js is very slow for layout switching. There is composite design pattern If you like to use **

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve through using CSS Media Queries, with the help of media queries you can maintain css for different layouts and you can hide the not needed things for mobile.

Comment: So for my above example, you're saying to create 2 divs with a navbar in one and a `select` in the other and hide them or show them based in the CSS related to the media query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Exactly. you can show Normal UL LI Nav for desktop and enable the Select dropdown nav for Mobile version using meida queries.

Comment: Ok fair enough. But you do see some sites completely redirect to rather than use media queries. Is the only time this is advantageous, is when the content of the site is completely different?